# Auto-update GEORSS feed in GoogleMaps?

Tags: maps, flickr, georss

I've created my own Google Map and entered the GEORSS feed from my Flickr account.

Geotagged photos display on the map perfectly.

However, when I add new photos with geotag data to Flickr, they don't appear on my Google Map.

**How can my Google Map auto update and show all new photos added to the Flickr GEORSS feed?**

It doesn't seem to auto-refresh.

If I import the feed again, the new photos show, but old photos are duplicated and now appear twice.

Cheers

Matt

Comment: The map is here http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=207522488362121337211.0004bb1539f152cc8f1f5

Comment: The Flickr feed I'm using is http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?id=77660406@N04&lang=en-us&format=rss_200